# About how best to question an edit

Tags: discussion, support

Some time ago, I asked a question... no answers were forthcoming... I continued to research.  After a while, I found the exact solution to the question I had asked.  I edited the question and provided the insight I had gained - as an update.  I accept that, perhaps, this wasn't the optimal strategy.

https://askubuntu.com/posts/517633/revisions

I was notified, today, that someone has edited my question to remove this information.  This doesn't strike me as an improvement... Now, the solution isn't associated with the question at all.

What is the most appropriate thing to do next?  Should I re-post the same information as an answer?  Can the edit be questioned?

I don't care who gets credit, or how it is (re)formatted - but I think it would be better if the answer remained.

What should I do for the best?  I don't want to get into an edit-war. :)

Comment: Check out the [self-learner badge](http://askubuntu.com/help/badges/14/self-learner).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about David's reasons behind completely redacting the info, but I don't believe that was the best behavior. He should have instead left a comment and told you what to do. Even though the solution shouldn't be posted in the question, it shouldn't just be removed without saying anything.

On the other hand, this is a Q&A site, not a forum. If you have a question and a solution, they need to be posted as such, in Q&A format. You added your solution later, but it should still have been posted as an answer and not added to the question.

Luckily, in this case, removing that info isn't that big of a deal. You seem to have gotten the hint that it shouldn't be part of the question, and since we have revision histories, it's easy to paste the text into an answer. David should really have left a comment instead of just making an edit like that, but to be fair, it isn't correct to have the answer in the question. (I suspect that David may have thought you to be inactive, since it's been a couple years, but a comment is still good.)

In the future, if you have a solution to your question, add it as an answer. After two days, you can accept it, so it's at the top. This'll avoid any of these problems (and you'll get more reputation from both a question and an answer than just a question ;) ).

I see your comment under anonymous2's answer here. There's nothing wrong with self-answering. You don't get the +2 rep of accepting an answer or the +15 of getting an answer accepted from this, so the assumption is it isn't for the rep. He linked you his Q&A, so I'll link you two of my own:

> [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics/)
>
> [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics)

Edits can definitely be questioned and disputed, and you did the right thing by coming to Meta to ask. Don't add it back to the question, because that'll definitely cause an edit war (it shouldn't be in the question). Just add it as an answer.

Comment: Great shares on the two links.  Good answer.

Comment: @anonymous2 well they are a bit more generalized :p

Answer (score 2):

Keep the question in the question box.  Do not put the answer to the question in the question box.  Underneath your question, you have a button that looks like this:

[image]

Click on it, and you will be greeted with the following dialog:

[image]

Click, "Yes, I want to post an answer," then put your answer into a *new* answer box.

If you put the answer into your question, it becomes confusing for future readers who see **Question** in big letters above your post and see `0 answers` below it.  For clarity's sake, put your answer on as a new post.  If you do not want to get any reputation off of it, you can always tick the `community wiki` box under the answer box.

Comment: Thanks - I'll do that.  I had previously assumed that posting an answer to one's own question is also a faux-pas.

Comment: @aSteve, there are even 2.9k people on this site who have earned the [self-learner](http://askubuntu.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) badge.